# Meteor: Tracker.autorun when Iron-Router Data Updates

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm using iron-router's `data` function to provide data to my HTML template.

***snippet from router.js:***

```
data: function() {
    liveData = {
      dataA: Collection.findOne({queryA}),
      dataB: Collection.findOne({queryB})
    };
    return liveData;
}
```

Within my template, the `liveData` object is reactive. When the Collection changes, liveData changes - great!

But my question: I have a javascript function called `computation()` within `Template.name.rendered` which uses the `liveData` object. It runs once on page load - great - but after the page is loaded, `liveData` is changing but the computation is not being re-run. How do I force `computation()` to re-run when iron-router's data source, `liveData`, changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Template.name.rendered = function(){
  this.autorun(function(){
    var data = Router.current().data();
    computation(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Switching `Router.current().data()` out for the `liveData` object variable does the trick!